# Phpstorm Intellisense / Code completion for inherited properties

Tags: intellisense, phpstorm, code-completion

I have a problem with Phpstorm's code completion for inherited properties. There is an example from my code below.

```
class ParentClass
{
  public $repository;
}

/*
 * @property Entity\SubClassRepository $repository
 */
class SubClass extends ParentClass
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->repository= $this->em->getRepository('Entity\Subclass');
  }

  public function ExampleFunction()
  {
    $this->repository-> !Here i need the code completion!
  }
}
```

The getRepository function returns SubClassRepository for param = Entity\SubClass or returns OtherClassRepository for param = Entity\OtherClass. Btw there is no exact type that it returns. Thus; i need to say Phpstorm what type $repository object of parent class is.

I know that Phpstorm uses Phpdoc notation for code completion. Thus i tried to use @property notation and added the lines below to SubClass.

```
/*
 * @property Entity\SubClassRepository $repository
 */
```

It doesn't work. Do you have any idea?
Thanks much.

Comment: This is NOT PHPDoc. PHPDoc starts with `/**` while you have normal comment `/*` -- see the difference?

Comment: Plus .. you missed `function` in `public __construct()` -- but I guess it's quick edit and copy-paste error/typo.

Comment: @LazyOne Oh, yea, i am missing the * as you said. Now it is working. Thanks you so much.

Comment: @LazyOne I missed the function keyword while asking question here. There is no problem about it. Thanks you so much again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was about my missing * character in annotations as @LazyOne said in his comment. @property tag is working perfect now.

It should read:

```
/**
 * @property Entity\SubClassRepository $repository
 */
```