# Typehinting through Zend_Registry::get() - how to make navigation to declaration understandable to PhpStorm?

Tags: php, ide, phpstorm

You can pass anything to `Zend_Registry::set('myWidget', $someWidget)`, [so that it's available later on](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.registry.using.html).

However, when you retrieve it elsewhere, PhpStorm IDE has no clues to the type of 'myWidget'.

```
<?php
class AwesomeWidget {
   public function doBazFlurgle() {
      // doesn't matter what exactly happens here
      return mt_rand();
   }
}
?>

<?php 
class FooController {

    public function init() {
        $someWidget = new AwesomeWidget();
        Zend_Registry::set('awesome', $someWidget);
    }

    public function barAction() {
        $this->init();
        $awesome = Zend_Registry::get('awesome');
        $awesomeNumber = $awesome->doBazFlurgle();
    }

}
```

`Navigate to declaration` on the `->doBazFlurgle()` call gets me a "Cannot find declaration to go to".

- [I could add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14663336/phpstorm-intellisense-code-completion-for-inherited-properties?rq=1) a `/** @var AwesomeWidget $awesome */` annotation, but that would require editing in many places in a sizable codebase
- [I could](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27465980/phpstorm-code-completion-not-working-on-php-methods/27531847#27531847) also [add a return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20992123/phpstorm-annotation-for-inherited-method-return-type) annotation to Zend_Registry, but that does not look very maintainable (there are many instances of different classes stored this way).
- I could search for the string `doBazFlurgle` through `Find In Path...`, but that is not entirely convenient (many keystrokes as opposed to a single Ctrl+click)

I noticed that NetBeans is capable of jumping to the method definition in this exact situation; is there a simple way of doing the same in PHPStorm without going through "search the entire codebase for `doBazFlurgle`"? I have searched available IDE actions, plugins, and fora; all in vain.

Comment: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Advanced+Metadata

Comment: @LazyOne: Wonderful, it works! Hard to find if you don't know what to search for ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way: as pointed out by [@LazyOne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/783119/lazyone), making a list of "what is returned from where" helps the IDE make sense of such code; this is [somewhat documented on Jetbrains' website](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Advanced+Metadata):

```
<?php
/** @link https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Advanced+Metadata */
// note that this is not valid PHP code, just a stub for the IDE
namespace PHPSTORM_META {
    $STATIC_METHOD_TYPES = [
        \Zend_Registry::get('') => [
            'awesome' instanceof \AwesomeWidget, // this is the class as seen in the question
            'fooSetting' instanceof \Zend_Config, // this came in from application settings
            'quuxData' instanceof \ArrayAccess, // an arraylike object
        ]
    ];
}
```

Including this file (named `.phpstorm.meta.php` by convention) in the project has resolved the issue. This file is *not* valid PHP - PhpStorm only uses it for typehinting. That way, `Zend_Registry::get('awesome')->doBazFlurgle()` is correctly resolved as calling the method on an instance of `\AwesomeWidget`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround:

- Position cursor into `doBazFlurgle` method call (click or cursor movement)
- Select word (`Ctrl+W`)
- Navigate to symbol (`Ctrl+Alt+Shift+N`)
- method will be offered in dropdown
- Select method (`Enter`)

Although this is not quite as clumsy as a generic string search, it is still not quite as convenient as the usual `navigate to declaration`.